# What`s the best approach for caching db results for slide show in php/ jquery

Tags: php, jquery, caching, slider

Hi, im implementing an slide show from a database, similar to facebook modal, but with just a image/video and a description.

I decided to use cached results for better performance, for now, im caching all results in an array and just ++/-- the index when the user press the arrow buttons. My code looks like :

```
var filesPrev, filesNext, initalFile = new Array();
var currentSlide; // represents the index/key of the current showed file
$(".imgLink").click(function() {
  idFile = $(this).attr("idFile");
  initialFile = load(idFile);  // pseudo code, it loads the first file
  loadImagesBefore(idFile).then(function(answer) { // get 10 images where id < idFile
    filesPrev = answer; // cache the results in an array
    loadImagesAfter(idFile).then(function(answer) { // get 10 images where id > idFile
            filesNext = answer.reverse(); // reverse just for ordering purposes
            //Now add both arrays (next/prev) and the firstFile(array) to slides array
            slides = filesNext;
            slides.push(initialFile);
            currentSlide = slides.length -1; // set current index/key to file(clicked)
            for (var i = 0; i < filesPrev.length; i++) {
                                  slides.push(filesPrev[i]); // push filesPrev to slides array;
            };
            openSlide(); // format view of first image

    });
  });
}
```

pseudo code for slide controller:

```
  leftkey.click(function() {
      currentSlide--;
      formatSlide(slide[currentSlide]);
      if (currentSlide == 1) {
        loadMoreFiles('next'); //caching again
      }
  });
  rightkey.click(function() {
      currentSlide++;
      formatSlide(slide[currentSlide]);
      if (currentSlide == slide.length) {
        loadMoreFiles('prev'); //caching again
      }
  });
```

The problem lies when there`s no more files to show left or right, and i want the slide to get the "otherside" results (like facebook, when you click the first photo, and press left, it will get you to the last photo).

I currently checking if the new loaded results wont match with the idFiles of the last filesPrev results. But im thinking if i cant do it in another way. Maybe with 2 arrays, one for prev, and other for next files, what you think is the better way to go? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? The Caching or the navigating?

Comment: The logic itself. Lets suppose im at idFile 5 (the img i clicked), i press left arrow until i`m at idFile 11, which is the last file user uploaded, than i call a request to load files where idFile > 1 LIMIT 10 (this way im loading the user files from beginning) and cache. But it will load idFile 5, which is already at cache, in this example, its ridiculous, but lets think that the user has 500 files. I should in every request check if all idFiles loaded (using for) havent already been cached? Or should i just forget the old files, and instead of using 2 arrays, loading just one (left or right)

Comment: Ah, So the problem is keeping track of the endpoints of the Cache?
You want to Cache all DL pictures for future load?